# Handling various frame layouts in Android

Tags: android, level-design, game-loop

I am trying create a Contra or the old TMNT game (but a simple one) like game for Android. For the game I decided to divide my main screen in three parts - upper for stats, mid for the game and lower for controls.

My main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/upper_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >
</FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/low_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.85" >
</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

So I have created the `gameview` and `gameloopthread` classes for the mid surface(which is pretty standard). My problem is I don't know how to draw in the upper and lower frame layouts. Should I make new classes for view and thread for each layout, should I do all this in the `gameview` class itself or is there any better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can now add the GUI and/or game components to the frames you've created.  This can be done either from Java code or in your XML layout (recommended).
For an example of both ways, please see this tutorial:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/